# Read single bytes from socket stream in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, arrays, byte

```
$data = socket_read($this->socket, 5);

    $counter = strlen($data); 
    for($i = 0; $i < $counter; ++$i) { 
        $char = (int)$data[$i]; 
        echo "\nByte $i: $char\n"; 
    }
```

The client sends two bytes to the server, and even when I read 5, it still only receives 2. The issue is that the byte is reading as 0. It's not reading it properly. How can I read the actual byte/byte array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client only sent two bytes, why do you want five? Try using [`socket_recv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php) instead to get explicit return value of bytes read.

Comment: I don't want five, I was just demonstrating that even if five were put in, then it only read two. I'll test using socket_recv now.

Comment: Hmm, no. You get two bytes. It's the peculiarity of PHP strings that confuses you.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the code to use socket_recv and set a variable to that. How would I read the actual value of the two bytes? I'm quite confused xD

Comment: Depends on what's in those bytes. Is it a string, an integer, something else?

Comment: the data is 2 individual bytes that need to be read separately, it is not a short.

Comment: Isn't that what PHP `unpack` is for? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

Comment: Maybe so. I'm very new to tampering with this type of stuff within PHP. Could you give me an example of how I would use unpack if I have the two bytes stored as a string in the variable "$var"? The string looks like this when echoed currently: http://i.imgur.com/Wcu4z.png

Comment: Yeah, PHP is not my first language either :)

Comment: I'm trying to read binary data and I have a class to convert it into my protocol. I just need to be able to read the data through the socket. I written the equivalent in java, but now I'm attempting to rewrite it to PHP. I know how it's supposed to work in java, it's just difficult in PHP.